# Retopology for Text and geometric shapes

Tags: add-on, retopology

Do you manually retopo your texts or use a specific tool for the task?

What would be a good tool for retopology of text and other geometric shapes in order to deform them properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are varying methods, but for text I generally use:

1 - *Decimate Modifier* (set to Planar)

2 - *Solidify Modifier*

3 - *Remesh Modifier* (Set to "Sharp" - Octree depth 6, 7 or 8 depending on precision needs - you may need to reduce the *Threshold* value to capture all the letters).

[image: Text]

Optional - Last step (If I want to use displacement) is to use a *Subdivision Surface Modifier* set to whatever level I need to achieve proper displacement.

Also optional, if you want more "clean" looking text is to use a *Bevel Modifier* (2 or 3 segments) before the *Subdivision Surface*

Comment: wow, thanks so much for the informative reply Chris!

Comment: Why the "Rim Only" option? It produces artifacts for me: https://imgur.com/a/ef8uVi1

Comment: I just figure almost all text is viewed from above - using "Only Rim" stops the bottom of the text from being filled with extra (most often) unseen polygons. If you have artifacts, just don't select it (as it only has a small purpose anyway)

Comment: But you're right - I put it more as a force of habit - it's insignificant enough (unless you have _lots_ of text) that it doesn't need to be in the primary instructions - I removed it :)